# How to navigate to the right div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

This is probably a noob question, but I'm trying to hide/show a popup video based on the associated thumbnail (a sibling div to the popup div) because for the site we want to be able to have multiple popup videos for some pages without coming up with unique ids/classes for every thumbnail-popup video pair. I've been using jquery to navigate the DOM in order to hide/show the correct popup video. So far, I've gotten that much working, but I need to be able to get the YouTube videos to stop playing whenever the popup is closed.

Since I don't think jquery has a built-in postMessage, I guess I have to use javascript for this task? But I'm having trouble figuring out how to navigate to the iframe that's within the right div.

Basically, for every video we have on a page, the html is set up like this:

```
<div class="smVidBox">
  <img alt="" style="float: right; margin-top: 5px;" title="gi_tinyvideo" src="/sf-images/architect/video_callout_prof.jpg?sfvrsn=0" />
</div> 
<div id="overlayBG"> 
    <div id="popupVideoBox"> 
        <div id="popupVideoTitle">Commercial Residential</div> 
        <div class="popupCloseBtn">
            <img src="/sf-images/design/videoclosebtn.jpg?sfvrsn=0" title="videoclosebtn" />
        </div> 
        <div id="popupVidContainer">
            <iframe width="605" height="340" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/url"></iframe> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So every thumbnail-popup pair is organized in this way. The current jquery/javascript looks like this:

```
$(".popupCloseBtn").click(function ()
{
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    $(this).hide();

    var div = document.getElementById("popupVidContainer");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    state = 'hide';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
```

But the javascript portion used to pause the video doesn't know which popupVidContainer to go to; it just goes to the first popupVidContainer it finds, which won't work for anything but, well, the first popupVidContainer.

So how can I navigate to the right popupVidContainer based on "this" popupCloseBtn?

(And yes, I know it's bad practice to have multiple IDs on a page. All that will probably be changed to classes at a later date.)

Edit: Answer has been found. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably be changed? It *has* to be changed or you'll get unpredictable results, just as you are now.

Comment: I echo what Jay said. You need to change your multiple IDs to classes. It's not just a bad practice, it's incorrect code.

Comment: If it was up to me, I would have changed them, but I'm only an intern and don't exactly have permission to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without id's (**but you really should change the id's so that each is unique within the page**) as long as the layout is consistent -

```
$(".popupCloseBtn").click(function ()
{
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    $(this).hide();

    //var div = document.getElementById("popupVidContainer"); // replacing this
    var div = $(this).parent().find('div:eq(2)'); // with this
    // var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
        iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    state = 'hide';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    //iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
    iframeDoc.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
}
```

Using the ability to traverse the DOM and knowing where the video container div is in relationship to its parent element will give you what you need.

Comment: But would I still be able to use the postMessage method by using jquery to traverse the DOM? Because if Google gave me the right results, jquery does not have that unless a plug-in is used, and I don't know if I can depend on YouTube to have that plug-in?

Comment: You should be able to, you'll have to test it to make sure.

Comment: What would getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow be in jquery? I put $(this).parent().find("iframe").contents(), but it's not working. But I also think I read that contents() doesn't work cross-domain? I'm sorry, I'm still a bit new to javascript/jquery.

Comment: I made changes so that you can see what I would do with your whole code block. I just replaced one line to rid ourselves of a need for id's.

Comment: I put the code exactly as you had it, but the video still won't pause like it's supposed to. For either popup.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Oh, yes, now that you mention that. "Undefined is not a function," which is referring to the "var iframe" line, so I guess it is trying to call getElementsByTagName as a function?

Comment: And now it's back to working for the very first iframe. I guess at this rate I'm going to have to use a for loop to handle the rest. I can't really think of any other way to handle the successive iframes without resorting to unique ids, which I probably won't be able to do (I'm an intern, so I don't have -as- much free reign over that stuff). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ooops - I forgot a small edit, replacing document with div. See edits.

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. I needed to change the jquery variable to $(this).parent().find('div:eq(2)')[0]. Now it seems to be working just fine. Thanks again!